# Command raised an exception: RequestException: error with request Invalid return character or leading space in header: User-Agent

Tags: python, discord.py, praw

So i have this discord bot that works well, and i decided to upload it to the cloud ( on replit ), the cogs works well except for one who's job is to import/load pictures ( memes in general ) from reddit and sending it on the channel, i receive this error :

Command raised an exception: RequestException: error with request Invalid return character or leading space in header: User-Agent

the code looks like this ( full code here https://replit.com/@moudii04/Testing#cogs/images.py ):

```
if REDDIT_APP_ID and REDDIT_APP_SECRET:
        # Init reddit's bot
        self.reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=REDDIT_APP_ID,
                                  client_secret=REDDIT_APP_SECRET,user_agent=f"bot-name:{REDDIT_APP_ID}:1.0")
```

I tried to look for spaces, but couldn't really find any.
Knowing that it works perfectly fine when i'm hosting it from my pc, but is bugging when used from the cloud, and that i simply copy/pasted all the bot's code part by part, and it's the only thing that is bugging.

Comment: Please post the *full* traceback and format it correctly.

Comment: I don't know really how but it simply started working, i have some internet issues those days, maybe it was a file that spent more time uploading.